# how to reverse date field from databse to xls file when using join

Tags: php, mysql, date, xls

I'm working with php mysql and I'm generating a XLS file from database values, but my problem is that the date field is coming through as `2014-01-05` but I want it to be `05-01-2014` in my XLS file. I'm showing all fields through a join query (so using `select *`), and that's why I'm unable to separate the date field to convert it into desired format. How can I achieve this?

Here is my SQL query to generate the XLS:

```
select * from  registration 
join programme on registration.id=programme.stuid 
join family on registration.id = family.stuid 
join address on registration.id = address.stuid 
join education on registration.id = education.stuid 
join extradetail on registration.id=extradetail.stuid 
join workexperience on registration.id=workexperience.stuid 
join demanddraft on registration.id = demanddraft.stuid 
where (DATE(demanddraft.ApporvedDate) >= '".$term1."' 
    AND DATE(demanddraft.ApporvedDate) <= '".$term2."') 
    AND demanddraft.ddstatus = 'Approved'
```

Here is the whole code for generating xls:

```
<?php

     $term1 = Date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_REQUEST['date1']));

      $term2 = Date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_REQUEST['date2']));

      $term3 = Date("d-m-Y",strtotime($term1));
      $term4 = Date("d-m-Y",strtotime($term2));

     $mode = $_REQUEST['mode'];
     $choice = $_REQUEST['choice'];
    if($mode == 'DD'){ 
     select * from  registration 
    join programme on registration.id=programme.stuid 
    join family on registration.id = family.stuid 
    join address on registration.id = address.stuid 
    join education on registration.id = education.stuid 
    join extradetail on registration.id=extradetail.stuid 
    join workexperience on registration.id=workexperience.stuid 
    join demanddraft on registration.id = demanddraft.stuid 
    where (DATE(demanddraft.ApporvedDate) >= '".$term1."' 
        AND DATE(demanddraft.ApporvedDate) <= '".$term2."') 
        AND demanddraft.ddstatus = 'Approved'


}

     //Optional: print out title to top of Excel or Word file with Timestamp
     //for when file was generated:
     //set $Use_Titel = 1 to generate title, 0 not to use title
     $Use_Title = 1;
     //define date for title: EDIT this to create the time-format you need
     $now_date = date('m-d-Y H:i');
     //define title for .doc or .xls file: EDIT this if you want
    $title = "Dump For Table $DB_TBLName from Database $DB_DBName on $now_date";
    //$date = date('d-M-Y');
     /*
     Leave the connection info below as it is:
     just edit the above.
     (Editing of code past this point recommended only for advanced users.)
     */
     //create MySQL connection
     $Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password)
         or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
     //select database
     $Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect)
         or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());
     //execute query
     $result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect)
         or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());
     //if this parameter is included ($w=1), file returned will be in word format ('.doc')
     //if parameter is not included, file returned will be in excel format ('.xls')
     if (isset($w) && ($w==1))
     {
         $file_type = "msword";
         $file_ending = "doc";
     }else {
         $file_type = "vnd.ms-excel";
         $file_ending = "xls";
     }
     //header info for browser: determines file type ('.doc' or '.xls')
     header("Content-Type: application/$file_type");
     //header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$DB_TBLName.$date.$file_ending");
     header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$DB_TBLName.$file_ending");
     header("Pragma: no-cache");
     header("Expires: 0");

     /*    Start of Formatting for Word or Excel    */
     if (isset($w) && ($w==1)) //check for $w again
     {
         /*    FORMATTING FOR WORD DOCUMENTS ('.doc')   */
         //create title with timestamp:
         if ($Use_Title == 1)
         {
             echo("$titlenn");
         }
         //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
         $sep = "\r"; //new line character
         while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
         {
             //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
             $schema_insert = "";
             for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
             {
             //define field names
             $field_name = mysql_field_name($result,$j);
             //will show name of fields
             $schema_insert .= "$field_name:t";


                 if(!isset($row[$j])) {
                     $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
                     }
                 elseif ($row[$j] != "") {
                     $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
                     }
                 else {
                     $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
                     }
             }
             $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
             $schema_insert .= "\t\n";
             print(trim($schema_insert));
             //end of each mysql row
             //creates line to separate data from each MySQL table row

             print "n----------------------------------------------------n";
         }
     }else{
         /*    FORMATTING FOR EXCEL DOCUMENTS ('.xls')   */
         //create title with timestamp:
         if ($Use_Title == 1)
         {
             echo("$titlen");
         }
         //define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)
         $sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
         //start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
         for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++)
         {
             echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";
         }
         print("\n");
         //end of printing column names
         //start while loop to get data
         while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
         {
             //set_time_limit(60); // HaRa
             $schema_insert = "";
             for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)
             {

               if(!isset($row[$j]))
                     $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;
                 elseif ($row[$j] != "")
                     $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;
                 else
                     $schema_insert .= "".$sep;
             }
             //$schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
             //following fix suggested by Josue (thanks, Josue!)
             //this corrects output in excel when table fields contain n or r
             //these two characters are now replaced with a space
             //$schema_insert = preg_replace('\n', ' ', $schema_insert);
            //$schema_insert = preg_replace("/n/", "", $schema_insert);         
        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);

        $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);

        $schema_insert .= "\t";

        print(trim($schema_insert));

        print "\n";


         }
     }
     ?>
```

Comment: Use strtotime() function.

Comment: Show the code that is creating the `XLS` file. Edit your question dont put it in a comment!

Comment: @ RiggsFolly: i have edited my question please check.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reformat the field that contains the date in question, I am assuming its called `DateFieldName` in my example.

Where you are processing through the result set from your query do something like this ...

```
//start while loop to get data
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    list($y,$m,$d) = explode( '-', $row['DateFieldName'] );
    $row['DateFieldName'] = sprintf( '%s-%s-%s', $d, $m, $y );
```